# How to add dots on the graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I got this question that how to add dots on a 2D graph, like the following picture.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rs501qkwqqk8qgk/abc.jpg

(the white dots and text on the above graph are needed to be added.)

I have plotted the graph, just do not know the command in matlab of adding the dots on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(Since there are not many details, I'll go with a generic answer)

If you have the dots coordinates in, say, vectors `X` and `Y`, you can plot them with:

```
hold on;           % Keep your plot while updating
plot(X, Y, 'ok');  % Black circles with white background
hold off;          % Allow your plots to refresh after that
```

Also, if you know where the text `'Tower'` should be drawn in the current axes (i.e. taking in account the axes limits), say, `x_text` and `y_text`, then:

```
hold on;
text(x_text, y_text, 'Tower');
hold off;
```

should do the job.

Comment: but how to put the white dots on the graph? what's the command for that? Thanks

Comment: Hi Kevin. If you are plotting data in a Matlab `figure`, the first command in my post (which you should insert it somewhere in the code after you decided **where** the white dots should appear) will do the trick. Did you try?

Comment: yes, I tried, it will show the black circle, but it will also erase the main graph.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rs501qkwqqk8qgk/abc.jpg the color graph on the link is the main graph ( I have plotted this figure), but adding the white dots stuck me...

Comment: Ok, the problem is holding on the past drawing operations, not just discarding them. I updated my post.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but the graph still does not show the dots. Here is my code:load('Wind_Hubs5080110.mat');/

Surf(X,Y,Hub_ws_50)/ 
shading interp/
axis equal/
view (0,90)/
colorbar/
hold on;/
plot(0,3000,'ok');/
hold off;/